# How to put the chapter number above the chapter heading?

Tags: chapters

The default looks something like this:

#### Chapter 1

### Chapter Title

I want it to look like this (but centered):

#### 1

### Chapter Title

In addition:

1. The chapter number should be bold, Large
2. The chapter title should be normal text, Large, uppercase.
3. I'd like to be able to control the spacing between the chapter number and the top of the page, the chapter number and the chapter title, and the chapter title and the body text.

Thanks!

EDIT. Here are some MWEs:

This one is the default. It doesn't do what I want at all:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Vector Spaces}
\end{document}
```

This one is closer, but doesn't have the chapter number above the chapter title:

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-5em}%
    {\parindent \z@  \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large\centering \thechapter \quad #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 2.5em
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{VECTOR SPACES}
\end{document}
```

This one also doesn't have uppercase font built into it. I had to capitalize the letters myself, which isn't a big problem but I'd still like it fixed.

Comment: read titlesec pack man

Comment: @JaredLo I don't have time to learn how to fish right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy option here is to redefine `\@chapapp` to just gobble its argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\let\@chapapp\@gobble
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Vector Spaces}
\end{document}
```

Why does this work? Look at `\@makechapterhead` (from [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)):

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

`\@chapapp` is always followed by `\space`. So, redefining it to `\@gobble` will just absorb `\space`.

---

In terms of your `\@makechapterhead` specification, here's some modifications:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-5em}% Space above number
    {\parindent \z@  \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large\centering \textbf{\thechapter}%
    \par\vspace{1em}% Space between number and title
    \MakeUppercase{#1}%
    \par\vspace{2.5em}% Space between title and text
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Vector Spaces}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can you make this work with the second MWE?

Comment: @fctaylor25: Change `\quad` to `\par`? I'll add some more detail to adhere to your requirements.

Comment: It almost works. It puts the number above the chapter title, but I'd like there to be more space in between. Also the number isn't bold.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about! It's perfect. Thanks Werner!

Comment: How would you modify this so that one could use `\chapter*`? It's not too hard to do this manually, but it would be nice to not have to.

Comment: @RandyRanderson: `\chapter*` uses `\@makeschapterhead` instead of `\@makehapterhead`. So, define your own `\@makeschapterhead` that matches the above `\@makechapterhead` only without the content related to `\thechapter` (as `\chapter*` doesn't print the chapter number).

Answer (score 4):

With `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}
{\LARGE\bfseries\thechapter}
{20pt}
{\Huge\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}
{}
{20pt}
{\Huge\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Vector Spaces}
Some text here.
\chapter*{Vector Spaces}
Some text here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok load this en the preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
.
.
.
.
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] % 
{\bfseries\Huge} %
{% Chapter label 

\filright 
%\Large\chaptertitlename\ % Name of Current chapter
\textbf{\Large\thechapter} % number of current chap 
} 
{0mm} % space between number of chapter and its name
{\filright} 
[\vspace{-1mm}\vspace{2pt}
]

\begin{doucument}
```